# Kafka Consumer ID disappears

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am facing this issue quite often, Consumer ID disappears for a topic (see the attached image). I am assuming that means there are no consumer available to consumer messages. what could be the reason any idea?

I am using confluent Kafka 5.5 version.

[image: Image of missing consumer id for a topic]

Comment: may be consumer are just not run?